# “bounded from above” vs. “bounded above”

Tags: mathematics

For unary functions f,g:X→Y, where X is any set and (Y,≤) is a poset, when you rephrase ∀ x∈X: f(x) ≤ g(x) in prose, do you write

1. "f is bounded above by g" or
2. "f is bounded from above by g" or
3. "f is majorized by g"?

Why?

Answer (score 2):

They say Math is the universal language -- it is beautiful in and of itself and only becomes ugly when you have to translate it into human speech.

To answer your question:  I don't recall the meaning of all the symbols in that equation, but from what I do understand, I believe the most common way to say this is "f **is bounded above** by g".

However since this is language highly specific to Math, not every English speaker will know what you mean, and it's likely that these kind of phrases have a specific *jargon* that is most common.  Also, Math is a field in which many are not native English speakers, so you'll probably hear a lot of variation.

As for "why" the answer is simply "convention".  g(x) is a function that describes the **upper bound** on f(x), yes?  Which is to say, f(x) can never exceed g(x).  So from what I recall from my various math classes, "bounded above" is simply what they say to describe this relationship.

Comment: @LeonMeier you mean you said you, personally, are a "monotonously growing function"?  That's actually hilariously clever.

Comment: @LeonMeier it's actually fine, it's what is called [self-deprecating humor](http://www.wikihow.com/Sample/Self-Deprecating-Humor).  The ability to do this well is considered a positive trait.  It says that while you may be *boring*, you're always *improving*.

Answer (score 1):

The normal usage in the US would be **bounded from above** rather than **bounded above**, which might be construed as being bounded from below. I have never heard of **majorized.** But the most common term in the US would be **less than or equal to.**

A standard translation of your symbols into spoken US English would be **For any x in the set X, f of X is less than or equal to g of x.**

You could confirm this with professional mathematicians by asking at non-commercial, free sites Math Help Forum or My Math Forum.